# Problem with tilde in \bibliography using BibTeX and RefTeX

Tags: bibtex, reftex

I have a problem using a tilde in the `\bibliography{}`. Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{ref09:man}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{~/bug.bib}
\end{document}
```

with "bug.bib" located in my home directory "~/" and defined as

> @Manual{ref09:man,
>    title =   {Reftex user manual, Version 4.34},
>    year =    2009
>   }

Now running "pdflatex" and then "bibtex", give then following error from BibTeX

```
White space in argument---line 4 of file d.aux
 : \bibdata{\protect
 :                   \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}/bug.bib}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file d.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "ref09:man"
```

This error can be fixed by using `\string~` instead of `~`, i.e.

```
\bibliography{\string~/bug.bib}
```

However, now there is a problem with RefTeX not finding the BibTeX database. When I enter `\cite` and hit return in emacs I get:

> No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available

(An absolute path would have solved this issue, e.g. `\bibliography{/home/userName/bug.bib}`, but I cannot use that since I use two machines one at home and one at work with different absoulte path to the home directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a directory  `$HOME/texmf/bibtex/bib` and put your bib files there.  Then you can use just `\bibliography{bug.bib}`, since both BibTeX and RefTeX search this directory (with the default settings).

Comment: Thank you this works fine.. I found that I can also use `export "BIBINPUTS=~"`

Comment: I did not know RefTeX checks BIBINPUTS - of course bibtex does...

Comment: No need to specify the file extension (`.bib`); it's better to write `\bibliography{bug}`.

Comment: @boris I think RefTeX also checks BIBINPUTS, see chapter 4.1 of the RefTeX manual.